# How do I make the element UI time picker set value only after the ok button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

Currently, the Element Timepicker triggers the `input` event (and, interestingly - not the `change` event as [mentioned in the docs](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/time-picker#events) ) every time the hours, minutes or seconds are changed. For my use case, I need it to allow the user to pick a value but not actually set the model (I'm using v-model but essentially, trigger an `input` event which `v-model` uses) until the user clicks the `ok` button.

I'm thinking a wrapper component which manages the state internally is one way to do it. (Sample implementation below)

Is there a cleaner way (ideally, built into Element and not involving hacks like below) to do this?

EDIT: It appears that I was wrong about change not being fired - as explained in @Roy J's answer below, it does fire when the button is clicked but crucially ALSO when the user just clicks out of the time picker after it is in focus which is not the behavior which is required - The model should update **only** when the ok button is clicked.

```
<template>
  <el-time-picker
    v-bind="_passthrough"
    :value="_displayValue"
    @blur="handleBlur"
    @focus="handleFocus"
    @input="handleInput"
  >
  </el-time-picker>
</template>

<script>
  import { TimePicker } from "element-ui";

  /**
   * A list of props accepted by the element time picker component
   * @private
   */
  const _elTimePickerProps = [
    "isRange",
    "readonly",
    "disabled",
    "editable",
    "clearable",
    "size",
    "placeholder",
    "startPlaceholder",
    "endPlaceholder",
    "arrowControl",
    "align",
    "popperClass",
    "pickerOptions",
    "rangeSeparator",
    "defaultValue",
    "valueFormat",
    "name",
    "unlinkPanels",
    "prefixIcon",
    "clearIcon",
    "value"
  ];

  /**
   * A wrapper on the element time picker to trigger the 'input' event only when the 'ok' button is clicked - lazily.
   * The actual element timepicker fires the input event every time an internal control is changed which is
   * undesirable in some cases.
   */
  export default {
    name: "LazyTimePicker",
    props: [..._elTimePickerProps], // Accept the same props as element time picker
    components: {
      ElTimePicker: TimePicker
    },
    data() {
      return {
        /**
         * Shadow to the value prop - used to update the value while the user is selecting without affecting the
         * globally bound value
         */
        currentValue: "",
        /**
         * Tracks if the element currently has focus
         */
        hasFocus: false
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleInput(value) {
        // Update the internal value every time the value is updated
        this.currentValue = value;
      },
      handleConfirm() {
        // Confirm button was clicked

        // Emit input event with the current value - plays nicely with v-model
        this.$emit("input", this.currentValue);

        // Remove the event listener on the confirm button
        this.$confirmButton.removeEventListener("click", this.handleConfirm);

        // Set the instance ref to the confirm button to undefined
        this.$confirmButton = undefined;
      },
      handleFocus() {
        // The time picker has gained focus, the dialogue will be open on the next tick
        // May be called multiple time (for example when switching between hours, minutes and seconds,
        // each switch triggers a focus event

        // Update focus state
        this.hasFocus = true;

        // Check if the one time setup is complete (indicated by the availability of the button ref on the
        // instance)
        if (this.$confirmButton) {
          // One time setup is complete, return early
          return;
        }
        // Initialise the instance's currentValue to the value received via props
        this.currentValue = this.value;

        // Wait until the time picker dialogue is open on the next tick as the confirm button will be on
        // the DOM only then
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // Get a ref to the confirm button
          const $confirmButton = document.querySelector(
            ".el-time-range-picker button.el-time-panel__btn.confirm"
          );

          // If the ref is available
          if ($confirmButton) {
            // Register click handler on the `ok` button
            $confirmButton.addEventListener("click", this.handleConfirm);

            // Keep a ref to the button for future use - also doubles as an indicator that the one time
            // setup that is done every time this component is opened is complete
            this.$confirmButton = $confirmButton;
          }
        });
      },
      handleBlur() {
        // The time picker has lost focus, the dialogue will be closed on the next tick
        this.hasFocus = false;

        this.$nextTick(() => {
          // Clean up the confirm button and it's event listener in case the user clicked out or pressed
          // cancel without pressing okay
          if (this.$confirmButton) {
            // Remove the event listener on the confirm button
            //Removing the listener here will prevent the input event from being emitted - does the listener get cleaned up?
            //this.$confirmButton.removeEventListener('click', this.handleConfirm);

            // Set the instance ref to the confirm button to undefined
            this.$confirmButton = undefined;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
      /**
       * Collect all props related to the actual element time picker to be `v-bind`ed to it in one shot
       * @returns {Object} Element time picker props
       * @private
       */
      _passthrough() {
        const self = this;
        return _elTimePickerProps.reduce(
          (acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: self[key] }),
          {}
        );
      },
      /**
       * The value to be displayed. When the element is not in focus (the dialogue is closed) the value in
       * the inputs should reflect the value bound to the time picker. When the element is in focus, the dialogue
       * will be open and the user will be in the process ofmaking their new selection. At this time, the inputs
       * should not show the value as it is currently being selected
       * @returns {string}
       * @private
       */
      _displayValue() {
        return this.hasFocus && this.currentValue
          ? this.currentValue
          : this.value;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It [emits a `change` event when you click `ok`](http://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/time-picker#events). So you can put a `change` handler on it to set the value. In the snippet below, `value` updates as you select, but `value2` only updates when you click `ok`.

Interestingly, `v-model.lazy` does *not* change the behavior to delay changing the value to after the `ok`. It seems to make no difference at all.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value1: '',
      value2: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changed(nv) {
      this.value2 = nv;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.4/lib/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.4/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="block">
    <el-time-picker v-model.lazy="value1" @change="changed" type="date" format="HH:mm:ss A">
    </el-time-picker>
    {{value1}}
  </div>
  {{value2}}
</div>
```

Comment: I could swear that I tried this and did not see the change event firing. I was probably doing something else wrong. Seeing a working example made me a believer and I got it working for me. Thanks :). PS: The link to the docs is broken [but the whole element website is weird like that]

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the link as well as it can be fixed.

Comment: I realised now what the problem was with this approach - This event get's triggered even if you do not click OK and click out. :( I'm going to mark this as not solved so it's open for answers again

Comment: I suspect you're out of luck.